# Parsing Specific lines from a pdb file using python

Tags: biopython

is there a way to parse the BFactor of a protein from its PDB file using Biopython/python?

I am trying with biopython but i am not able to fetch the b factor of the proteins of my interest.

Comment: https://biopython.org/docs/dev/api/Bio.PDB.Atom.html seems to me you can access atom bfactor the same way you access its coordinates, In the case of PQR files, B factor and occupancy are replaced by atomic charge and radius. SEE in the wiki https://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ#analysis

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

with `test.pdb` :

```
ATOM      1  N   THR A   1      32.504  37.205  19.346  1.00 35.93           N  
ATOM      2  CA  THR A   1      33.806  36.685  19.869  1.00 33.83           C  
ATOM      3  C   THR A   1      35.000  37.216  19.097  1.00 34.05           C  
ATOM      4  O   THR A   1      34.831  37.956  18.112  1.00 37.45           O  
ATOM      5  CB  THR A   1      33.780  35.136  19.858  1.00 35.93           C  
ATOM      6  OG1 THR A   1      34.996  34.712  20.476  1.00 29.78           O  
ATOM      7  CG2 THR A   1      33.677  34.608  18.436  1.00 28.68           C  
ATOM      8  N   ASN A   2      36.222  36.900  19.493  1.00 27.70           N  
ATOM      9  CA  ASN A   2      37.466  37.312  18.870  1.00 26.38           C  
ATOM     10  C   ASN A   2      37.890  36.323  17.772  1.00 23.63           C  
ATOM     11  O   ASN A   2      37.108  35.426  17.477  1.00 26.11           O  
ATOM     12  CB  ASN A   2      38.573  37.472  19.903  1.00 26.18           C  
ATOM     13  CG  ASN A   2      38.854  36.188  20.687  1.00 23.57           C  
ATOM     14  OD1 ASN A   2      38.219  35.168  20.445  1.00 24.27           O  
ATOM     15  ND2 ASN A   2      39.763  36.310  21.648  1.00 25.69           N  
ATOM     16  N   ALA A   3      39.078  36.497  17.205  1.00 27.65           N  
ATOM     17  CA  ALA A   3      39.537  35.641  16.112  1.00 27.70           C  
ATOM     18  C   ALA A   3      39.734  34.176  16.518  1.00 27.15           C  
ATOM     19  O   ALA A   3      39.174  33.270  15.869  1.00 26.97           O  
ATOM     20  CB  ALA A   3      40.807  36.208  15.498  1.00 27.00           C  
ATOM     21  N   THR A   4      40.123  33.960  17.768  1.00 24.83           N  
ATOM     22  CA  THR A   4      40.236  32.608  18.357  1.00 21.65           C  
ATOM     23  C   THR A   4      38.868  31.997  18.531  1.00 22.46           C  
ATOM     24  O   THR A   4      38.571  30.833  18.173  1.00 22.18           O  
ATOM     25  CB  THR A   4      40.984  32.761  19.690  1.00 19.96           C  
ATOM     26  OG1 THR A   4      42.296  33.274  19.425  1.00 28.59           O  
ATOM     27  CG2 THR A   4      41.111  31.396  20.390  1.00 23.74           C
```

and code :

```
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser


from Bio import  __version__


print('########## Biopython  VERSION #####################################')
print('\n BIOPYTHON_VERSION : ', __version__ ,'\n')
print('###################################################################')

structure = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE = False , QUIET=False).get_structure('X', 'test.pdb')

        
print('\n---------------------------------------------------\n')



atom_list = structure.get_atoms()  ## its actually a generator , that get emptied when cycled

print('atom_list : \n ', [i for i in atom_list],'\n\n')


atom_list = structure.get_atoms() ## its actually a generator , that get emptied when cycled

print('atom      ----------------> bfactor')

for atom in atom_list:
    
    print( atom ,' : ',  atom.get_serial_number() , ' -----------> ' , atom.get_bfactor())
```

output :

```
########## Biopython  VERSION #####################################

 BIOPYTHON_VERSION :  1.75 

###################################################################

---------------------------------------------------

atom_list : 
  [<Atom N>, <Atom CA>, <Atom C>, <Atom O>, <Atom CB>, <Atom OG1>, <Atom CG2>, <Atom N>, <Atom CA>, <Atom C>, <Atom O>, <Atom CB>, <Atom CG>, <Atom OD1>, <Atom ND2>, <Atom N>, <Atom CA>, <Atom C>, <Atom O>, <Atom CB>, <Atom N>, <Atom CA>, <Atom C>, <Atom O>, <Atom CB>, <Atom OG1>, <Atom CG2>] 


atom      ----------------> bfactor
<Atom N>  :  1  ----------->  35.93
<Atom CA>  :  2  ----------->  33.83
<Atom C>  :  3  ----------->  34.05
<Atom O>  :  4  ----------->  37.45
<Atom CB>  :  5  ----------->  35.93
<Atom OG1>  :  6  ----------->  29.78
<Atom CG2>  :  7  ----------->  28.68
<Atom N>  :  8  ----------->  27.7
<Atom CA>  :  9  ----------->  26.38
<Atom C>  :  10  ----------->  23.63
<Atom O>  :  11  ----------->  26.11
<Atom CB>  :  12  ----------->  26.18
<Atom CG>  :  13  ----------->  23.57
<Atom OD1>  :  14  ----------->  24.27
<Atom ND2>  :  15  ----------->  25.69
<Atom N>  :  16  ----------->  27.65
<Atom CA>  :  17  ----------->  27.7
<Atom C>  :  18  ----------->  27.15
<Atom O>  :  19  ----------->  26.97
<Atom CB>  :  20  ----------->  27.0
<Atom N>  :  21  ----------->  24.83
<Atom CA>  :  22  ----------->  21.65
<Atom C>  :  23  ----------->  22.46
<Atom O>  :  24  ----------->  22.18
<Atom CB>  :  25  ----------->  19.96
<Atom OG1>  :  26  ----------->  28.59
<Atom CG2>  :  27  ----------->  23.74
```